# Building Apache Nutch Docker container

Tags: dockerfile, nutch

I am following the instructions for installing Apache Nutch at:

https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nutch
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nutch/dockerfile

```
# NOTE TO DEVELOPERS: Make sure this file passes linting tests
# by running https://github.com/replicatedhq/dockerfilelint

# BUILD_MODE can be either
#  0 == Nutch master branch source install with 'crawl' and 'nutch' scripts on PATH
#  1 == Same as mode 0 with addition of Nutch REST Server
#  2 == Same as mode 1 with addition of Nutch WebApp
ARG BUILD_MODE=0

FROM alpine:3.13 AS base

ARG SERVER_PORT=8081
ARG SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
ARG WEBAPP_PORT=8080

LABEL maintainer="Apache Nutch Developers <dev@nutch.apache.org>"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="Apache Nutch Developers <dev@nutch.apache.org>"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.description="Docker image for running Apache Nutch, a highly extensible and scalable open source web crawler software project. Visit the project website at https://nutch.apache.org"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.documentation="https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nutch"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.licenses="Apache-2.0"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/nutch/master/docker/Dockerfile"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="Apache Nutch 1.x Docker Image"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.url="https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nutch"
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.vendor="Apache Nutch https://nutch.apache.org"

WORKDIR /root/

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update
RUN apk add apache-ant bash git openjdk11 supervisor

# Establish environment variables
RUN echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk' >> $HOME/.bashrc
ENV JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk'
ENV NUTCH_HOME='/root/nutch_source/runtime/local'

# Checkout and build the Nutch master branch (1.x)
RUN git clone https://github.com/apache/nutch.git nutch_source && \
     cd nutch_source && \
     ant runtime && \
     rm -rf build/ && \
     rm -rf /root/.ivy2/

# Create symlinks for runtime/local/bin/nutch and runtime/local/bin/crawl
RUN ln -sf $NUTCH_HOME/bin/nutch /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -sf $NUTCH_HOME/bin/crawl /usr/local/bin/

FROM base AS branch-version-0

RUN echo "Nutch master branch source install with 'crawl' and 'nutch' scripts on PATH"

FROM base AS branch-version-1

RUN echo "Nutch master branch source install with 'crawl' and 'nutch' scripts on PATH and Nutch REST Server on $SERVER_HOST:$SERVER_PORT"
ARG SERVER_PORT=8081
ARG SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0

ENV SERVER_PORT=$SERVER_PORT
ENV SERVER_HOST=$SERVER_HOST

# Arrange necessary setup for supervisord
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisord
COPY ./config/supervisord_startserver.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Expose port for server which can only be accessed if 
# the same port is published when the container is run.
EXPOSE $SERVER_PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisord.conf" ]

FROM base AS branch-version-2

RUN echo "Nutch master branch source install with 'crawl' and 'nutch' scripts on PATH, Nutch REST Server on $SERVER_HOST:$SERVER_PORT and WebApp on this container port $WEBAPP_PORT"
ARG SERVER_PORT=8081
ARG SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
ARG WEBAPP_PORT=8080

ENV SERVER_PORT=$SERVER_PORT
ENV SERVER_HOST=$SERVER_HOST
ENV WEBAPP_PORT=$WEBAPP_PORT

# Install the webapp
RUN apk add maven
RUN git clone https://github.com/apache/nutch-webapp.git nutch_webapp && cd nutch_webapp && mvn package

# Arrange necessary setup for supervisord
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisord
COPY ./config/supervisord_startserver_webapp.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

# Expose ports for server and webapp, these can only be accessed if 
# the same ports are published when the container is run.
EXPOSE $SERVER_PORT
EXPOSE $WEBAPP_PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "supervisord", "--nodaemon", "--configuration", "/etc/supervisord.conf" ]

FROM branch-version-$BUILD_MODE AS final
RUN echo "Successfully built image, see https://s.apache.org/m5933 for guidance on running a container instance."
```

> => ERROR [branch-version-2 5/5] COPY
> ./config/supervisord_startserver_webapp.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
> 0.0s
>
> ---
>
> > [branch-version-2 5/5] COPY ./config/supervisord_startserver_webapp.conf /etc/supervisord.conf:
> > ------ failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3360673970/config: lstat
> > /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3360673970/config: no such file or
> > directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I downloaded the https://github.com/apache/nutch project to my working dir.

Then you may find the docker dir and inside that dir there is the Dockerfile with the config dir that has the files that are missing for you to build the image.